# Why does this not print true

Tags: python

Call me dumber than a barrel of hay in a barn in the outback thats been roasting for 20 eons but I can't see why this is not working. I am new to python and trying to practice what I learned in class today.

When I run this it does not print true which is what I need it to do and instead just prints 5 twice. I am confused as to why this is not printing true

Code

```
a = [1,5,3], [4,5,6]

def atest():
    atwo = a[0][1]
    return atwo

def btest():
    btwo = a[1][1]
    return btwo

if btest == atest():
    print("true")

print(atest())
print(btest())
```

Output

```
5
5
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Shorn it's comparing the *function object* not function signature

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the correction, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing the `()` at the end of `btest` when you compare it to `atest()`.

Comment: Precisely. `f` is a function reference, `f()` is a function call.